# ASP.NET MVC hosted in GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path, asp.net-mvc-5, hosting

I've been working on a ASP.NET MVC website and It's been hosted in GoDaddy. You can directly send an inquire form to a specific email in the website I'm making, It's working perfectly fine, the form is sending without a problem, until I hosted it. Whenever I try to send a form, I keep getting this error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'G:\PleskVhosts\sellurs.com\httpdocs\App_Data\uploads\SOS.docx'

But when I try to run my project that is not hosted, the form is still sending without a problem. Why is that? Here's my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            List<string> paths = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    paths.Add(path);
                }
            }

                var message = new MailMessage();
                foreach (var path in paths)
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
                }

                //Rest of business logic here
                string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
                bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
                if (IsCaptchaValid)
                {

                    var body = "<p><b>Email From:</b> {0} ({1})</p><p><b>Subject:</b> {2} </p><p><b>Message:</b></p><p>{3}</p><p><b>Description:</b></p><p>{4}</p>";
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***"));  // replace with valid value 
                    message.From = new MailAddress("***");  // replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "(Inquire)";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message, model.Desc);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        var credential = new NetworkCredential
                        {
                            UserName = "***",  // replace with valid value
                            Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                        };
                        smtp.Credentials = credential;
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            //delete attached files
                            foreach (var path in paths)
                                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        };
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                        ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return View("Index");
                    }
                } else

                {
                    TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
                }

            } return View(model);

        }
```

I think the problem is in the pathing, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. Someone please help me. I'm just new with this kind of stuffs. Thank you in advance. And also, when the website was hosted the navigation bar becomes blue, but in the local host it's black. And the background picture is not showing in the hosted website. Pleeease help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this type of error occur in following case

case1: you haven't set permission to create file programmatically/by IIS so you have to change permission from your cpanel.

case2: file path may contain special character but in your case there is all plain text

Soln:
 use file exist to check whether file is exist or not so you can figure out whats wrong going on. all the best....

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir. I already checked the " Allow inheritable permissions from the parent to propagate to this object and all child objects. Include these with the entries explicitly defined here " permission. But I still get the same error. The path is just used to temporarily store the files that will be uploaded. But it will not be save in the folder. Hope you could help me Sir. Thank you.

Comment: your code is perfect, you have to use try catch and print all the things in log so you can figure out whats going wrong. according to my experience there is only permission related things are void to create file.

Comment: Hi Sir, it been a while. :) Thank you for the help. My code it working now, the mail is sending. But somehow the ViewBag that's going to say "Your message has been sent!" is not showing even tho I already receive the message in my email. Here's my code Sir: http://pastie.org/10906936 I hope you can help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: try to use this                                                'HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()'